# Convert json into an object of a class that contains a template variable using gson

Tags: java, android, gson

My Api response looks like this.

```
{
    "status" : 1,
    "message" : "Some Message",
    "data" : {
    }
}
```

My Response class looks like this. The type of data changes depending on the request being made.

```
public class Response<T>{
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("status")
    private Integer status;

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("message")
    private String message;

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("data")
    private T data;

    //Getters and Setters
}
```

Question 1. How to use gson to parse this json?

```
Response<ClassA> response = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, ??);
```

Question 2. How would i write Parcelable implementation for this class.

```
dest.writeInt(status == null ? 0:status);
dest.writeString(message);
??
```

Comment: Have you done any of your own research?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.

Question 1:

```
Response<ClassA> response = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, new TypeToken<Response<ClassA>>(){}.getType());
```

Question 2:

Changed class to this.

```
public class Response<T extends Parcelable>{
@Expose
@SerializedName("status")
private Integer status;

@Expose
@SerializedName("message")
private String message;

@Expose
@SerializedName("data")
private T data;

//Getters and Setters

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    if (data != null) {
        dest.writeString(data.getClass().getName());
        dest.writeParcelable(data, flags);
    } else dest.writeString(null);
    dest.writeString(message);
    dest.writeInt(status);
}
}

protected Response(Parcel in) {
    String className = in.readString();
    if (className != null) {
        try {
            data = in.readParcelable(Class.forName(className).getClassLoader());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    message = in.readString();
    status = in.readInt();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some changes in your Model structure. To do this..

Create a BaseDTO which is nothing but your Response class and extend your BaseDTO with your ClassA.

BaseDto.class

```
public class BaseDto {
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("status")
    protected Integer status;

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("message")
    protected String message;

    public Integer getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(Integer status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

ClassA.class

```
public class ClassA extends BaseDto implements Parcelable {

    String name;

    protected ClassA(Parcel in) {
        name = in.readString();
        status = in.readByte() == 0x00 ? null : in.readInt();
        message = in.readString();
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(name);
        if (status == null) {
            dest.writeByte((byte) (0x00));
        } else {
            dest.writeByte((byte) (0x01));
            dest.writeInt(status);
        }
        dest.writeString(message);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<ClassA> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<ClassA>() {
        @Override
        public ClassA createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new ClassA(in);
        }

        @Override
        public ClassA[] newArray(int size) {
            return new ClassA[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Use this site to generate Parcelable class http://www.parcelabler.com/

to parse using gson you just need to pass it's type to it..

I have written a function to simplify this..
Save these in a Util class

```
public static <T> String convertObjectToStringJson(T someObject, Type type) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String strJson = gson.toJson(someObject, type);
    return strJson;
}

public static <T> T getObjectFromJson(String json, Type type) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    if (json != null) {
        if (json.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
    }
    return gson.fromJson(json, type);
}
```

example to use these function:

```
ClassA classA = Util.getObjectFromJson(strJson, new TypeToken<ClassA>() {}.getType());

String jsonClassA = Util.convertObjectToStringJson(objClassA, new TypeToken<ClassA>() {}.getType());
```

Comment: Not the solution i was looking for. Thanks anyways.

Comment: What do you think about the solution that i have posted. The solution to question 1 is the best way according to me. I am a little dicey about the solution to the second question though.